# Jquery - how to get class name of div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this div in my layout. I am new to jQuery. So I want to know class name of div.

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code

```
 var className = $('.demo').attr('class');
```

You can refer here,

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp